# Value does not insert correctly in my Table

Tags: python, django

It is appeared that my value from my form does not insert correctly in my table. Below are my code:-

## my Forms.py ##

```
class AerialPhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AerialFoto
            fields = ['year_id', 'scale_id', 'index_id', 'location_id', 'size']

## my Views.py ##

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AerialPhotoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
    form.save()

## my Models.py ##

class AerialFoto(models.Model):
    AerialFoto_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    index_id = models.ForeignKey(No_index, null=True, blank=True)
    scale_id = models.ForeignKey(Scale, null=True, blank=True)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True)
    year_id = models.ForeignKey(Year, null=True, blank=True)
    file_directory = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    gsd = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

And the result that i've got:-

[My Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZCMz.jpg)

Comment: You mean by 'Year Object', 'Location Object', etc?

Comment: Where's the rest of your view? Is the form actually valid? Are you showing errors in the template? Do you actually see any errors?

Comment: @Gocht yes.. the object..

Comment: @DanielRoseman 

i don't have any error when submit

Answer (score 0):

To see a verbose expression of an object, you need to define a `__unicoide__` (or `__str__` if python 3.x) method in your models:

```
class Location(models.Model):

    ...
    name = models.CharField.....

    def __unicode__(self):  # or __str__ if python 3
        return self.name  # assuming you have a name field, you can use any string field.
        # You could return any string here to test
        # e.g. return 'This is my object'
```

And the same for `No_Index`, `Scale` and `Year` models.

Comment: @IamMoon I'm glad this helped you, consider accepting this answer as correct answer. Cheers.